# Cloudfront CDN integration with Magento

Tags: magento, amazon-web-services, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I have searched a lot but still didn't get the way to sync **media, css and js** data with **Cloudfront CDN**.

Please help and let me know how can I do this thing.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Check your Base URL for SKIN, JS and Media for CDN under magento admin

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked a lot with Magento, but a straight approach can be scheduling a cron task in your management node to sync up your static files with a S3 bucket. [S3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) is your friend here.

Then simply set your Cloudfrount distribution's Origin to your S3 bucket and set the static resource URLs in Magento to [use your Cloudfront endpoint](http://www.thirdandgrove.com/blog/2014/03/magento-amazon-cloudfront.html).